# Axiom of choice - Proving an equivalence

Tags: logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I am reading a book on set theory and I got stuck on a simple step of a proof involving an equivalence of the axiom of choice.

> **Axiom of Choice (1)** *For every set $a\neq \emptyset$ there exists a function $f:\mathcal{P}\left (a\right )\setminus \left \{\emptyset\right \}\to a$ such that $f\left (b\right )\in b$ for every $b\subseteq a$, $b\neq \emptyset$*
>
> **Axiom of Choice (2)** *Let $\left \{a_i\right \}_{i\in I}$ be a non-empty family of pairwise disjoint non-empty sets (i.e. $I\neq \emptyset$ and $a_i\cap a_j=\emptyset$ if $i\neq j$). Then there exists a set $d$ such that $d\cap a_i$ is a unit set for every $i\in I$.*

I could understand the proof $\left (2\right )\Rightarrow \left (1\right )$, but I cannot understand the converse.

The proof starts by supposing that $\left (1\right )$ is true. We let $\left \{a_i\right \}_{i\in I}$ be a non-empty family of pairwise disjoint non-empty sets and define $a=\bigcup_{i\in I}a_i\neq \emptyset$. Therefore there exists a function $f:\mathcal{P}\left (a\right )\setminus \left \{\emptyset\right \}\to a$ be a function such that $f\left (b\right )\in b$ for every $b\in \mathcal{P}\left (a\right )\setminus \left \{\emptyset\right \}$. If $d$ is the image of $f$, then (the book says) we have $d\cap a_i=\left \{f\left (a_i\right )\right \}$. My question is: Why? It is obvious that one of the inclusions holds, but what about $\subseteq$?

Comment: Restrict $f$ to $\{a_i\} \subset \mathcal{P}(a)$.

Comment: @ZachTeitler: Eh? You don't need to use choice to choose from singletons.

Comment: That would be a restriction to a unit subset of the domain of $f$, the only thing I should do is applying $f$ to $a_i$ and then I obtain that $f\left (a_i\right )\in d\cap a_i$ which gives us the trivial inclusion. What about the other one?

Comment: @AsafKaragila $a_i$ is not a singleton. Restrict $f$ to the collection $\{a_i\}_{i \in I}$. Version (1) provides a choice for *every* subset of $a$; we only care about the subsets $a_i$ for $i \in I$.

Comment: @Zach: Yes. But $\{a_i\}$ is a singleton. If you mean something else, then you should use the proper notation or proper explanation to set the context.

Comment: @solomeoparedes I don't understand your question. You have a set $d$, $d = \{ f(a_i) \mid i \in I \}$. For each $i \in I$, $f(a_i) \in a_i$, so $f(a_i) \in d \cap a_i$. On the other hand $a_j \cap a_i = \varnothing$ for $i \neq j$. So for $j \neq i$, $f(a_j) \notin d \cap a_i$. So if $x \in d \cap a_i$, then $x = f(a_j)$ for some $j$, and it must be $j = i$. So $d \cap a_i = \{f(a_i)\}$, a singleton.

Comment: Oh, I see. The problem was that the book did not define $d$ as you did. The book defined $d$ as the whole image of $f$. Can we assume that it is an errata?

Comment: @solomeoparedes Perhaps they defined $d$ in that way *after* restricting $f$ from all of $\mathcal{P}(a)$ to the subcollection $\{a_i\}_{i \in I}$? (Which by the way, some people would sometimes denote $\{a_i\}$, leaving the indexing $i \in I$ implicit, especially in certain contexts like writing $(a_n)$ for a sequence, or when they are typing on their phones.)

Comment: what's the name of the book? I'd like to see this statement myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that $a=\bigcup_{i\in I}a_i$ is trivially a superset of each of the $a_i$'s. Therefore each $a_i$ is an element of $\mathcal P(a)$.

By assumption, no $a_i$ is empty, so $a_i$ is in the domain of the choice function. Now take $\{f(a_i)\mid i\in I\}$ to be $d$, and by the fact each $a_i$ is disjoint we get that $d\cap a_i$ is a singleton for all $i\in I$.

Comment: So, as I said on a previous comment: Should I assume that the book has an errata? Because the book defined $d$ as the whole image of $f$, not just the image of the $a_i$.

Comment: Always assume there is an errata, and if you tried and checked, and there is an obvious mistake, you can assume it's the obvious mistake.